# Echarts - Keep current position echarts after updating data

Tags: echarts

I am trying to keep current Echarts position after updating data (like stock chart have new price but we are in past time).

I am using setOption with opts: { lazyUpdate: true, replaceMerge: ['xAxis', 'yAxis', 'series'] } but nothing works.

https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#echartsInstance.setOption

Comment: Did you figure anything out about this? I have the same problem, and it is driving me crazy.

Comment: Did you resolve that issue?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in updating scroll position from options.

```
 dataZoom: [
  {
    type: 'inside',
    start: 0,
    end: 10
  },
  {
    start: 0,
    end: 10
  }
],
…
```

you have to make handler for keeping new scroll/zoom

```
chart.on("datazoom", e => last_datazoom = e)
```

and before updating data write `last_datazoom` start-end to your 'option' `dataZoom start-end`.